# relation between class number of an algebraic number field and its Galois closure

Tags: analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields

I read some results of C. Parry, F. Lemmermeyer and etc, about the class number formula in the special number fields, for example for any pure number field of a prime degree. Now I want to investigate for finding a similar formula for a non- Galois number field K of degree a prime number p such that  its Galois closure has Galois group D_p, the Dihedral group of order 2p.

I ndeed I want to find a answer for this question: "Is there a relation between class number of K and class number of its Galois closure?"

Comment: Castela, Halter-Koch, Jehne